# Why isn't JavaScript onchange event changing the value sent to the server on my VBScript page using POST method?

Tags: vbscript

I have a select form on a ASP Classic/HTML5 web page as follows:

```
<form id="my-form" name="my-form" method="POST">
    <select name="year" onchange="submitMyForm()">
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The header of my ASP Classic page handles the form request using VBScript as follows:

```
<%
Dim formYear
formYear = Resquest.Form("year")

Response.Write(formYear)

%>
```

My JS code only does the following

```
<script>
    function submitMyForm() {
        document.getElementById("my-form").submit();
    }
</script>
```

My problem is that when I'd change the value of the select, the `onchange` event would get triggered, but my VBScript code wouldn't get the correct value, only would be stuck with the same value of the beginning.

Note: I'm submitting the form to the same page where it is.

Comment: `<form>` tag should include `action` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is working for me - but it is not triggering when selecting 2010 because that is the default and you are "not changing" the current value (since that is what it was when the page loaded). Perhaps add the selected value as well - so if the value changes, you will then see it?

```
<select name="year" onchange="submitMyForm();">
<% If (len(formYear) > 0) Then %>
 <option value="<%=formYear%>" selected><%=formYear%></option>
<% End If %>
 <option value="2010">2010</option>
 <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>
```